# "policy_enforced" error when exchange oauth2 token for google plus

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

Our app used to work fine until last Tue. We kept getting "policy_enforced" error while exchange oauth2 token for google plus. The response from google is:

```
Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponseException: 
Error:"policy_enforced", 
Description:"Access denied by a security policy established by the Google Apps administrator of your organization. Please contact your administrator for further assistance.", 
Uri:""
```

We're using google-api-dotnet-client and the code is straight forward enough.

```
var flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
{
    DataStore = new CustomGoogleDataStore(),
    ClientSecrets = new global::Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ClientSecrets { ClientId = client.ID, ClientSecret = client.Secret },
    Scopes = scopes.Split(' '),
});
var token = flow.ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync(guid, code, redirectUri, CancellationToken.None).Result;
```

The scopes are:

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
"https://mail.google.com/"
```

This issue happens randomly. Util now I cannot find a way to 100% reproduce it.

Please let me know what this issue is and any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. But sometime it works fine. If it's caused by the scope issue it would have been totally down.

Comment: I have been trying to reproduce it. What APIs do you have enabled in cloud console?

Comment: The following APIs are enabled:Admin SDK, BigQuery API, Calendar API, Chrome Web Store API, Contacts API, Drive API, Google Apps Marketplace API, Google Apps Marketplace SDK, Google Cloud SQL, Google Cloud Storage, Google Cloud Storage JSON API , Google+ API, Google+ Domains API, Google+ Hangouts API, Tasks API, Ad Exchange Buyer API

Comment: you are using an older client lib I wonder if it has anything to do with that.   I cant recreate it with the current clientlib

Comment: Did you follow the error suggestion and contact your administrator???

Comment: @DalmTo - Thanks for your suggestion. I'll update the client lib and see if it resolved this issue.

Comment: @DaImTo - I've upgraded the lib to the latest one. unfortunately we're still getting this error. Do you know what this error message means?

Comment: Ping... Did you follow the error suggestion and contact your administrator?

Comment: @peleyal - what do you mean administrator here? there're 3 parties in this case: 1. I who developed this app, obviously I don't know what the problem is 2. the user who uses our app and wants to do google plus integration. They don't know what happened actually. 3. google - I'm asking here for google. Who do you think I should contact?

Comment: When you say randomly, do you mean the same user authorizing repeatedly will sometimes work and sometimes fail? Or do you mean that some users consistently work and some users consistently fail? There's a huge difference there.

Comment: @SteveBazyl - this is a good question! I tested with different google domain. 1. with 1 existing domain it always failed regardless using admin/normal user account; 2. with another new created domain it succeeded on both admin/normal user account; would it have something to do with the account settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same problem recently. After contacting Google team we found this problem occurred because of mismatch between the authorized scopes and what we are requesting at login time. We used latest Authorization scopes [profile](https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login) and [email](https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read) while user login. But in GAM API console Google hardcoded the deprecated scopes 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email

After reverting the latest Authorization scopes to deprecated scopes login works fine.

Comment: after days of running on production it proved this is the correct answer. thanks Barani!