# policy_enforced Error When Exchanging oAuth2 token from Google

Tags: oauth-2.0

Our app used to work fine until August 26th, 2014. We kept getting "policy_enforced" error while exchange oauth2 token for google plus. The response from google is:

Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponseException: 
Error:"policy_enforced", 
Description:"Access denied by a security policy established by the Google Apps administrator of your organization. Please contact your administrator for further assistance.", 
Uri:""

There are others having this issue, and we never changed our code, it just stopped working, for exapmple here: ["policy_enforced" error when exchange oauth2 token for google plus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25508740/policy-enforced-error-when-exchange-oauth2-token-for-google-plus)

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Answered in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25508740/policy-enforced-error-when-exchange-oauth2-token-for-google-plus/26182693#26182693). Making use of deprecated scopes will fix this problem.